# Local \theorempreskipamount and \theorempostskipamount of ntheorem

Tags: spacing, ntheorem

It seems that `\theorempreskipamount` and `\theorempostskipamount` cannot be set locally meaning that they will keep the same value for all the defined environments even though the user may wish different values for theorems, definitions or proofs. Is there a work around to avoid that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: Do you wish to have different `\theorempreskipamount` and `\theorempostskipamount` for different environments like theorems, definitions and proofs? Or do you wish all the environments to have the same `\...skipamount`? Or do you want some **theorems** to have a different `\...skipamount` to other **theorems**.

Comment: your first guess is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using, for example, `\theoremprework` you can set those lengths for particular groups of theorem-like structures:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}   

\theoremprework{%
\setlength\theorempreskipamount{1ex}\setlength\theorempostskipamount{1ex}
}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}
\theoremprework{%
\setlength\theorempreskipamount{1cm}\setlength\theorempostskipamount{1cm}
}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{defi}
test
\end{defi}    
\lipsum[1]
\begin{theo}
test
\end{theo}    
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the `thmtools` front-end, you can define custom styles with their own values for `spaceabove`, `spacebelow`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}   

\declaretheoremstyle[spaceabove=1ex, spacebelow=1ex]{styleone}
\declaretheorem[style=styleone]{theorem}
\declaretheoremstyle[spaceabove=1cm, spacebelow=1cm]{styletwo}
\declaretheorem[style=styletwo]{definition}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{definition}
test
\end{definition}    
\lipsum[1]
\begin{theorem}
test
\end{theorem}    
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```